Kafka Infinite Retry Only Happening till 1 minute
I am using Spring Kafka in my application.There are two consumers in my application. I have given infinite retry implementation in both consumers. But when an exception occurs,
it is only retrying till 1 minute and after that it stops.It is only happening in one of the consumers but not happening in the other one.The exception being thrown is same in both consumers. The configuration is same for both consumers , only the topics,clientIds are different.
Here is my consumer configuration where retry happening till 1 minute
//Not working infinite retry
@Service
public class RecurrentJobKafkaListenerManager {

@Value("${scheduler.kafka.endpoint}")
private String schedulerKafkaEndpoint;

@Autowired
private ScheduleRecurrentJobListener scheduleJobListener;

@Value("${scheduler.kafka.topics.prefix}")
private String schedulerKafkaTopicPrefix;

@Value("${scheduler.job.kafka.concurrency:1}")
private int concurrency;

@Value("${scheduler.recurrent.job.kafka.maxpollrecords:1}")
private int maxPollRecords;

@Autowired
private KafkaACLConfig kafkaACLConfig;

private ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, ScheduleRecurrentJob> concurrentMessageListenerContainer = null;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, schedulerKafkaEndpoint);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "scheduleRecurrentConsumer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    if(kafkaACLConfig.isEnabled()) {
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, kafkaACLConfig.getSecurityProtocol());
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, kafkaACLConfig.getSaslMechanism());
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"" + kafkaACLConfig.getUsername() + "\" password=\"" + kafkaACLConfig.getPassword() + "\";");
    }
    ConsumerFactory<String, ScheduleRecurrentJob> consumer = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props,
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(ScheduleRecurrentJob.class));

    ContainerProperties consumerProperties = new ContainerProperties(schedulerKafkaTopicPrefix + Constants.SCHEDULE_RECURRENT_TOPIC);
    consumerProperties.setMessageListener(scheduleJobListener);
    consumerProperties.setClientId(schedulerKafkaTopicPrefix + Constants.SCHEDULE_RECURRENT_TOPIC + "-Consumer");

    concurrentMessageListenerContainer = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
            consumer, consumerProperties);
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000L,FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS)));
    startConsuming();

}

public void startConsuming() {
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.start();

}

@PreDestroy
public void stopConsuming() {
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.stop();
}

}

Here is the working one with infinite retries
@Service
public class WindowKafkaListenerManager {

@Value("${scheduler.kafka.endpoint}")
private String schedulerKafkaEndpoint;

@Autowired
private ScheduleWindowListener scheduleWindowListener;

@Value("${scheduler.kafka.topics.prefix}")
private String schedulerKafkaTopicPrefix;

@Value("${scheduler.window.kafka.concurrency:1}")
private int concurrency;

@Autowired
private KafkaACLConfig kafkaACLConfig;

private ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, SchedulerWindowStatus> concurrentMessageListenerContainer = null;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, schedulerKafkaEndpoint);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "scheduleWindowConsumer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    if(kafkaACLConfig.isEnabled()) {
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, kafkaACLConfig.getSecurityProtocol());
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, kafkaACLConfig.getSaslMechanism());
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"" + kafkaACLConfig.getUsername() + "\" password=\"" + kafkaACLConfig.getPassword() + "\";");
    }
    ConsumerFactory<String, SchedulerWindowStatus> consumer = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props,
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(SchedulerWindowStatus.class));

    ContainerProperties consumerProperties = new ContainerProperties(schedulerKafkaTopicPrefix + Constants.SCHEDULE_WINDOW_TOPIC);
    consumerProperties.setMessageListener(scheduleWindowListener);
    consumerProperties.setClientId(schedulerKafkaTopicPrefix + Constants.SCHEDULE_WINDOW_TOPIC + "-Consumer");

    concurrentMessageListenerContainer = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
            consumer, consumerProperties);
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000L,FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS)));
    startConsuming();

}

public void startConsuming() {
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.start();

}

@PreDestroy
public void stopConsuming() {
    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.stop();
}

}

I debugged it and checked all the properties in the container object , all are same, but not able to find out what is the cause for it.
